# Webpack / Typescript - ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module?

Tags: typescript, webpack

The project builds fine when `mode = "development"`, but but not `"production"` - everything is `"not an ECMAScript module"`.

Production mode automatically uses `ModuleConcatenationPlugin`, development doesn't so that makes sense, but I can't figure out why `ModuleConcatenation` is unhappy.

The Webpack docs say "Keep in mind that this plugin will only be applied to ES6 modules processed directly by webpack. When using a transpiler, you'll need to disable module processing (e.g. the modules option in Babel)" - I haven't been able to find a way to do that for typescript other than setting the "module" compiler option to "es6"?

Any insights or suggestions on how to track down the problem would be appreciated - I've burned a day on this already :(

My tsconfig.json:

```js
{
    "include": [
        "src/browser/**/*",
        "src/shared/typings/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/public/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

The webpack.config:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  mode: "production",

  entry: './src/browser/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        options: {
          useCache: false,
          configFileName: 'test.tsconfig.json'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.tsx',
      '.ts',
      '.js'
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I (eventually) figured it out.

Something I thought was a warning was being flagged as an error by typescript.

This caused NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin to do it's thing and produce no output

ModuleConcatenationPlugin therefore has nothing to do, but less-than-helpfully throws "...not an ECMAScript module" errors - AKA a massive red herring.

So, future Googlers - make sure ModuleConcatenationPlugin actually has modules to concatenate!

Comment: Can you elaborate? what exactly did you do to fix this?

Comment: To clarify, my code had a compile error. This meant no compiled output was produced. ModuleConcatenationPlugin had no compiled output to work with, but the error it produced was unhelpful.

So, there wasn't anything to fix as such - when my code compiled everything was fine